# Traversing a tree (recursive) that contains properties in the form of both ordinary values ​and objects and arrays

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a beautiful way to iterate over an object that contains properties from both ordinary values ​​and from objects, arrays.

I want to iterate over the input and output the fields in the form {name: 'value'} to display them on the page.

How to correctly and gracefully recursively traverse a given tree? or any other good way

```
 let initial ={
      name: 'Data',
      property1: {name: 'first'},
      property3: [
        { name: 'Название', value: 'Some text' },
        {
          name: 'text',
          name1: 'Some text"'
        },
        { name: 'text', value: '030444003223' },
        { name: 'Code', value: '15' },
        { name: 'Phone', value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' },
        { name: 'Email', value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' }
    ]
}
```

#### Expected

I need just to iterate through the tree and get data in turn like  `=> {name: 'Data'}`

the initial value can be an Array

```
let initial = [
            { name: 'Название', value: 'Some text' },
            {
              name: 'text',
              name1: 'Some text"'
            },
            { name: 'text', value: '030444003223' },
            { name: 'Code', value: '15' },
            { name: 'Phone', value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' },
            { name: 'Email', value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' }
        ]
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Why do you think `Object.entries` cannot be used on an Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a good case for a generator. Using the `*` and `yield` notation you can implement the recursive logic and separate it from the actual iteration.

The iteration can then happen with a `for..of` loop, or any other available way to iterate over the values of an iterable.

Here I propose that each iteration will give you the **path** (as an array of property names) and the **value** that is found there. For arrays, the property will appear as the index number.

It may be surprising to see `Object.entries` used on arrays, but an array is also an object, so it is quite fine to call `Object.entries()` on it.

Here is the generator, and your example:

```js
function * iter(obj, path=[]) {
    if (Object(obj) !== obj) return yield [[...path], obj];
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) yield * iter(v, path.concat(k));
}

// demo
let obj = {
    name: 'Data',
    property1: {name: 'first'},
    property3: [
        { name: 'Название', value: 'Some text' },
        {
          name: 'text',
          name1: 'Some text"'
        },
        { name: 'text', value: '030444003223' },
        { name: 'Code', value: '15' },
        { name: 'Phone', value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' },
        { name: 'Email', value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' }
    ]
};

for (let [path, value] of iter(obj)) {
    console.log(path.join("."), "=", value);
}
```

If you are not interested in the path, but just the deepest key, then just pop that key from the `path` that you get while iterating. For instance:

```
for (let [path, value] of iter(obj)) {
    console.log(path.pop(), value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could itrrate the entries and take the name property or check all other properties and if objects call the function again.

```js
const
    getValues = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((r, [k, v], i) => {
            if (v && typeof v === 'object') r.push(...getValues(v));
            else r[0] = { ...r[0], [k]: v };
            return r;
        }, [[]])
        .flat();
    object = { name: 'Data', property1: { name: 'first' }, property3: [{ name: 'Название', value: 'Some text' }, { name: 'text', name1: 'Some text"' }, { name: 'text', value: '030444003223' }, { name: 'Code', value: '15' }, { name: 'Phone', value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' }, { name: 'Email', value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' }] },
    values = getValues(object);

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It is not clear exactly what you are looking for from your question, but with this solution there is a lot of flexibility.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData1 = { name: 'Data', property1: { name: 'first' }, property3: [ { name: 'Название', value: 'Some text' }, { name: 'text', name1: 'Some text"' }, { name: 'text', value: '030444003223' }, { name: 'Code', value: '15' }, { name: 'Phone', value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' }, { name: 'Email', value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' } ] };

const myData2 = [ { name: 'Название', value: 'Some text' }, { name: 'text', name1: 'Some text"' }, { name: 'text', value: '030444003223' }, { name: 'Code', value: '15' }, { name: 'Phone', value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' }, { name: 'Email', value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' } ];

const scan1 = (data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  reverse: false,
  filterFn: ({ isLeaf, property, value, context }) => {
    if (isLeaf) {
      context.push({ [property]: value });
    }
  }
})(data, []);

const scan2 = (data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  joined: true,
  reverse: false,
  filterFn: ({ isLeaf, key, value, context }) => {
    if (isLeaf) {
      context.push({ [key]: value });
    }
  }
})(data, []);

console.log(scan1(myData1));
// => [ { name: 'Data' }, { name: 'first' }, { name: 'Название' }, { value: 'Some text' }, { name: 'text' }, { name1: 'Some text"' }, { name: 'text' }, { value: '030444003223' }, { name: 'Code' }, { value: '15' }, { name: 'Phone' }, { value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' }, { name: 'Email' }, { value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' } ]
console.log(scan1(myData2));
// => [ { name: 'Название' }, { value: 'Some text' }, { name: 'text' }, { name1: 'Some text"' }, { name: 'text' }, { value: '030444003223' }, { name: 'Code' }, { value: '15' }, { name: 'Phone' }, { value: '+7 (723) 269 86 33' }, { name: 'Email' }, { value: 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' } ]

console.log(scan2(myData1));
// => [ { name: 'Data' }, { 'property1.name': 'first' }, { 'property3[0].name': 'Название' }, { 'property3[0].value': 'Some text' }, { 'property3[1].name': 'text' }, { 'property3[1].name1': 'Some text"' }, { 'property3[2].name': 'text' }, { 'property3[2].value': '030444003223' }, { 'property3[3].name': 'Code' }, { 'property3[3].value': '15' }, { 'property3[4].name': 'Phone' }, { 'property3[4].value': '+7 (723) 269 86 33' }, { 'property3[5].name': 'Email' }, { 'property3[5].value': 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' } ]
console.log(scan2(myData2));
// => [ { '[0].name': 'Название' }, { '[0].value': 'Some text' }, { '[1].name': 'text' }, { '[1].name1': 'Some text"' }, { '[2].name': 'text' }, { '[2].value': '030444003223' }, { '[3].name': 'Code' }, { '[3].value': '15' }, { '[4].name': 'Phone' }, { '[4].value': '+7 (723) 269 86 33' }, { '[5].name': 'Email' }, { '[5].value': 'dsds_db@tadsn-s.hz' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)